# Inserting in the sqlite with exesql

Tags: java, sqlite

i need a tip here , here i have a code to insert into sqlite database:

```
 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + name
        + "  (ID           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + "   Type            TEXT,"
        + "   Text         TEXT,"
        + "   OtherFormats           TEXT,"
        + "   Date           TEXT,"
        + "   Image     TEXT,"
        + "   RealName TEXT)";
db.execSQL(sqlCreate);


//(String Type, String Text ,String name,String OtherFormats,String Itime,String   
 RealName)
String sqlInsert= "INSERT INTO " + "'"+name+"'" +
" VALUES     
("+"'"+ID+"'"+","+"'"+Type+"'"+","+"'"+Text+"'"+","+
"'"+OtherFormats+"'"+","+"'"+Date+"'"+"  
,"+"'"+Image+"'"+","+"'"+RealName+"')"; 

db.execSQL(sqlInsert);
          }

    });
t.start();
```

the question is as you u see my ID is auto increment, but for executing it well, i need to put a value there,what value should i put so it database does the increament itself?
thanks

```
 05-26 03:56:33.018: E/AndroidRuntime(23809):   

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:     near "VALUES": syntax error (code 1): ,   
while compiling: INSERT INTO 'new' (Type,Text,OtherFormats ,Date,Image,RealName VALUES('m','hey','n','03:56','j','s')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Enter the name of columns you need to insert

```
String sqlInsert= "INSERT INTO " + "'"+name+"' (Type,Text,OtherFormats ,Date,Image,RealName )VALUES     
("+"'"+ID+"'"+","+"'"+Type+"'"+","+"'"+Text+"'"+","+
"'"+OtherFormats+"'"+","+"'"+Date+"'"+"  
,"+"'"+Image+"'"+","+"'"+RealName+"')"; 

db.execSQL(sqlInsert);
```

Comment: now im receiving a new error on compile, i just update the post of you could help please

Comment: @user3673818 what kind of error? PLease post the message.

Comment: oh i lost 1 ")" seems :/

Answer (score 0):

> the question is as you u see my ID is auto increment, but for executing it well, i need to put a value there,what value should i put so it database does the increament itself?

Put in a `NULL` or just leave it unspecified.

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> If no ROWID is specified on the insert, or if the specified ROWID has a value of NULL, then an appropriate ROWID is created automatically.